# Display text in jtextarea with newline and spacing

Tags: java, swing, newline, jtextarea

I have set the text of `JTextArea` with setText function

```
abc="PREFIX table: <http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/PeriodicTable#> " +
            "SELECT ?name " +
            "FROM <http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/PeriodicTable.owl>" +
            "WHERE {" +
            "      ?element table:name ?name. " +
            "      FILTER(str(?name)=\"sodium\") " +
            "      }"
texta.setText(abc);//abc is very long string
```

How do I display the string with newlines and spacing in the `JTextArea`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
abc="PREFIX table: <http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/PeriodicTable#>\n" +
        "SELECT ?name\n" +
        "FROM <http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/PeriodicTable.owl>\n" +
        "WHERE {\n" +
        "      ?element table:name ?name.\n" +
        "      FILTER(str(?name)=\"sodium\")\n" +
        "      }"
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use new lines in your String.  The `'\n'` character.